# Expiración de Session en Oauth

Tags: web, oauth

Tengo la siguiente duda sobre la `Session` cuando se usa `Oauth` como autenticación , como sabemos en una `Session Web` , esta se mantiene activa ( al menos en la mayoría de los casos ) y cuando se queda inactiva es borrada por el servidor, en caso de usarla de nuevo antes de ese tiempo , la `Session` toma de nuevo el tiempo máximo y así hasta que no se use todo ese tiempo de expiración de `Session`. Y si el usuario intenta ingresar de nuevo entonces es redireccionado a el `login`.

> ```
> Session Inactiva Time out 10 minutos.
> Si usuario usa a los 5 minutos de estar inactivo este tiempo se resetea de nuevo a 10.
> este ciclo puede repetirse horas.
> cuando finalmente usuario deja inactivo la web por 10 minutos recien se invalida y cuando un momento use se redireccionara al login
> ```
>
> .

En `Oauth` como puedo simular este mismo comportamiento porque al haber un `access token` que ya tiene un expiración por defecto no es lo mismo, se necesita otra cosa para simular que esta expiración es variable.
También hay el `refresh token` este nos permite obtener mas `access tokens` pero igual no sirve ni simula el comportamiento de una `Session` web, hay algún ejemplo para lograr eso ?

> Comportamiento Se loguean se le da un access token que es usado hasta
>   que ya no sirva por un tiempo X que no se aumenta , una ves terminado
>   este tiempo ya no hay mas y tendra que logearse de nuevo para obtener
>   uno nuevo
>
> Se loguean se le da un `access token` que es usado hasta que ya no sirva
>   por un tiempo X que no se aumenta , una ves terminado este tiempo usa
>   el `refresh token` que puede durar meses o años y va obteniendo `access token.`

Comment: Se me ocurre que cuando el usuario entre le emitas de nuevo el access token con con el tiempo nuevo, pero tendrias que redirigirlo al endpoint de oauth de alguna manera y saltarte algunas partes del proceso, no se si los clientes oauth permitan eso...

Comment: Estaba pensando usar un header mas como un session id para controlar esto de la expiracion y un scope para detectarlo y usarlo , en caso de no hacerlo el oauth trabajaria normalmente como dice la especificacion y asi podria usar el api como una web normal , no si es correcto y no violo nada del standar.